# Select most recent note from each record

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking to retrieve the most recent note per date for all rows.
I am able to do it using a simple script but i cannot put it into my query without grouping by..
I tried to do this same thing in SSRS, but it seems to not workout.

This is my simple query:

```
select MAX(A.DateCol) MOT_Date ,
A.TextCol as Note,
B.Case_Id

from AMGR_Notes_Tbl A
inner join AMGR_CSCases_Tbl B on A.Client_Id = B.Case_Id

where a.DateCol between '20201201' and '20201231'
group by a.TextCol, a.DateCol, b.Case_Id
```

The above works 100% on a simple query..

I just cannot incorporate it into my main query below:

```
Select   case when CS.Contact_Id is null or CS.Contact_Id = '' then DRSpec1.AlphanumericCol else DRSpec2.AlphanumericCol end as Dr_Specialty
        ,case when CS.Contact_Id is null or CS.Contact_Id = '' then RL.AlphanumericCol else RL2.AlphanumericCol end as Regional_Location
        ,case when CS.Contact_Id is null or CS.Contact_Id = '' then TCN.AlphanumericCol else TCN2.AlphanumericCol end as Tracker_Case_No
        ,Case When CS.Contact_Id is null or CS.Contact_Id = '' then DocVal.Description else Doc2Val.Description end as Doctor
        ,Case When CS.Contact_Id is null or CS.Contact_Id = '' then MedAidVal.Description else MedAid2Val.Description end as Medical_Scheme
        ,Case When CS.Contact_Id is null or CS.Contact_Id = '' then MOVal.Description else MO2Val.Description end as Medical_Scheme_option
        ,Case When CS.Contact_Id is null or CS.Contact_Id = '' then PCVal.Description else PC2Val.Description end as PC
        ,Case When CS.Contact_Id is null or CS.Contact_Id = '' then DCVal.Description else DC2Val.Description end as DC
        ,case when CS.Contact_Id is null or CS.Contact_Id = '' then PCRD.DateCol else PCRD2.DateCol end as PC_R_Date
        ,case when CS.Contact_Id is null or CS.Contact_Id = '' then DRRD.DateCol else DRRD2.DateCol end as Dr_R_Date
        ,CS.Description
        ,'HQ-'+Right('00000' + Cast(CS.Sequence_Number as varchar(5)),5) as Client_Name
        ,Notes.TextCol as Interactions
        ,Notes.DateCol as NoteDate
        ,RDSVal.Description as RDS
        ,RMVal.Description as RM
        ,SCVal.Description as SC
        ,SRVal.Description as SR
        ,APPVal.Description as Appeal
        ,Status.Description as Status

--First joins in the from clause get the address book user defined fields

From  dbo.AMGR_CSCases_Tbl CS
     Left Outer Join dbo.AMGR_User_Fields_Tbl DrSpec1
     on CS.Client_Id = DrSpec1.Client_Id and CS.Client_Number = DrSpec1.Contact_Number and DrSpec1.Type_Id = 109
     Left Outer Join dbo.AMGR_User_Fields_Tbl DrSpec2
     on CS.Contact_Id = DrSpec2.Client_Id and CS.Contact_Number = DrSpec2.Contact_Number and DrSpec2.Type_Id = 109

     Left Outer Join dbo.AMGR_User_Fields_Tbl RL
     on CS.Client_Id = RL.Client_Id and CS.Client_Number = RL.Contact_Number and RL.Type_Id = 110
     Left Outer Join dbo.AMGR_User_Fields_Tbl RL2
     on CS.Contact_Id = RL2.Client_Id and CS.Contact_Number = RL2.Contact_Number and RL2.Type_Id = 110

     Left Outer Join dbo.AMGR_User_Fields_Tbl TCN
     on CS.Client_Id = TCN.Client_Id and CS.Client_Number = TCN.Contact_Number and TCN.Type_Id = 124
     Left Outer Join dbo.AMGR_User_Fields_Tbl TCN2
     on CS.Contact_Id = TCN2.Client_Id and CS.Contact_Number = TCN2.Contact_Number and TCN2.Type_Id = 124

     Left Outer Join dbo.AMGR_User_Fields_Tbl PCRD
     on CS.Client_Id = PCRD.Client_Id and CS.Client_Number = PCRD.Contact_Number and PCRD.Type_Id = 106
     Left Outer Join dbo.AMGR_User_Fields_Tbl PCRD2
     on CS.Contact_Id = PCRD2.Client_Id and CS.Contact_Number = PCRD2.Contact_Number and PCRD2.Type_Id = 106

     Left Outer Join dbo.AMGR_User_Fields_Tbl DRRD
     on CS.Client_Id = DRRD.Client_Id and CS.Client_Number = DRRD.Contact_Number and DRRD.Type_Id = 107
     Left Outer Join dbo.AMGR_User_Fields_Tbl DRRD2
     on CS.Contact_Id = DRRD2.Client_Id and CS.Contact_Number = DRRD2.Contact_Number and DRRD2.Type_Id = 107

     Left Outer Join dbo.AMGR_User_Fields_Tbl Doc
     on CS.Client_Id = Doc.Client_Id and CS.Client_Number = Doc.Contact_Number and Doc.Type_Id = 103
     Left Outer Join dbo.AMGR_User_Field_Defs_Tbl DocVal
     on Doc.Type_Id = DocVal.Type_Id and Doc.Code_Id = DocVal.Code_Id and Doc.Type_Id = 103 and DocVal.Table_Id = 2

     Left Outer Join dbo.AMGR_User_Fields_Tbl Doc2
     on CS.Contact_Id = Doc2.Client_Id and CS.Contact_Number = Doc2.Contact_Number and Doc2.Type_Id = 103
     Left Outer Join dbo.AMGR_User_Field_Defs_Tbl Doc2Val
     on Doc2.Type_Id = Doc2Val.Type_Id and Doc2.Code_Id = Doc2Val.Code_Id and Doc2.Type_Id = 103 and Doc2Val.Table_Id = 2

     Left Outer Join dbo.AMGR_User_Fields_Tbl MedAid
     on CS.Client_Id = MedAid.Client_Id and CS.Client_Number = MedAid.Contact_Number and MedAid.Type_Id = 24
     Left Outer Join dbo.AMGR_User_Field_Defs_Tbl MedAidVal
     on MedAid.Type_Id = MedAidVal.Type_Id and MedAid.Code_Id = MedAidVal.Code_Id and MedAid.Type_Id = 24 and MedAidVal.Table_Id = 2

     Left Outer Join dbo.AMGR_User_Fields_Tbl MedAid2
     on CS.Contact_Id = MedAid2.Client_Id and CS.Contact_Number = MedAid2.Contact_Number and MedAid2.Type_Id = 24
     Left Outer Join dbo.AMGR_User_Field_Defs_Tbl MedAid2Val
     on MedAid2.Type_Id = MedAid2Val.Type_Id and MedAid2.Code_Id = MedAid2Val.Code_Id and MedAid2.Type_Id = 24 and MedAid2Val.Table_Id = 2

     Left Outer Join dbo.AMGR_User_Fields_Tbl MO
     on CS.Client_Id = MO.Client_Id and CS.Client_Number = MO.Contact_Number and MO.Type_Id = 28
     Left Outer Join dbo.AMGR_User_Field_Defs_Tbl MOVal
     on MO.Type_Id = MOVal.Type_Id and MO.Code_Id = MOVal.Code_Id and MO.Type_Id = 28 and MOVal.Table_Id = 2

     Left Outer Join dbo.AMGR_User_Fields_Tbl MO2
     on CS.Contact_Id = MO2.Client_Id and CS.Contact_Number = MO2.Contact_Number and MO2.Type_Id = 28
     Left Outer Join dbo.AMGR_User_Field_Defs_Tbl MO2Val
     on MO2.Type_Id = MO2Val.Type_Id and MO2.Code_Id = MO2Val.Code_Id and MO2.Type_Id = 28 and MO2Val.Table_Id = 2

     Left Outer Join dbo.AMGR_User_Fields_Tbl PC
     on CS.Client_Id = PC.Client_Id and CS.Client_Number = PC.Contact_Number and PC.Type_Id = 115
     Left Outer Join dbo.AMGR_User_Field_Defs_Tbl PCVal
     on PC.Type_Id = PCVal.Type_Id and PC.Code_Id = PCVal.Code_Id and PC.Type_Id = 115 and PCVal.Table_Id = 2

     Left Outer Join dbo.AMGR_User_Fields_Tbl PC2
     on CS.Contact_Id = PC2.Client_Id and CS.Contact_Number = PC2.Contact_Number and PC2.Type_Id = 115
     Left Outer Join dbo.AMGR_User_Field_Defs_Tbl PC2Val
     on PC2.Type_Id = PC2Val.Type_Id and PC2.Code_Id = PC2Val.Code_Id and PC2.Type_Id = 115 and PC2Val.Table_Id = 2

     Left Outer Join dbo.AMGR_User_Fields_Tbl DC
     on CS.Client_Id = DC.Client_Id and CS.Client_Number = DC.Contact_Number and DC.Type_Id = 121
     Left Outer Join dbo.AMGR_User_Field_Defs_Tbl DCVal
     on DC.Type_Id = DCVal.Type_Id and DC.Code_Id = DCVal.Code_Id and DC.Type_Id = 121 and DCVal.Table_Id = 2

     Left Outer Join dbo.AMGR_User_Fields_Tbl DC2
     on CS.Contact_Id = DC2.Client_Id and CS.Contact_Number = DC2.Contact_Number and DC2.Type_Id = 121
     Left Outer Join dbo.AMGR_User_Field_Defs_Tbl DC2Val
     on DC2.Type_Id = DC2Val.Type_Id and DC2.Code_Id = DC2Val.Code_Id and DC2.Type_Id = 121 and DC2Val.Table_Id = 2

--This next join gets the client name data
     Left Outer Join dbo.AMGR_Client_Tbl ComInd
     on CS.Client_ID = ComInd.Client_Id and Cs.Client_Number = ComInd.Contact_Number
     Left Outer Join dbo.AMGR_Client_Tbl Cont
     on CS.Contact_ID = Cont.Client_Id and Cs.Contact_Number = Cont.Contact_Number

--The following get the CS Case user defined fields and case status values

     Left Outer Join dbo.AMGR_User_Fields_Tbl RDS
     on CS.Case_Id = RDS.Client_Id and RDS.Type_Id = 118
     Left Outer Join dbo.AMGR_User_Field_Defs_Tbl RDSVal
     on RDS.Type_Id = RDSVal.Type_Id and RDS.Code_Id = RDSVal.Code_Id and RDS.Type_Id = 118 and RDSVal.Table_Id = 2

     Left Outer Join dbo.AMGR_User_Fields_Tbl RM
     on CS.Case_Id = RM.Client_Id and RM.Type_Id = 128
     Left Outer Join dbo.AMGR_User_Field_Defs_Tbl RMVal
     on RM.Type_Id = RMVal.Type_Id and RM.Code_Id = RMVal.Code_Id and RM.Type_Id = 128 and RMVal.Table_Id = 2

     Left Outer Join dbo.AMGR_User_Fields_Tbl SC
     on CS.Case_Id = SC.Client_Id and SC.Type_Id = 119
     Left Outer Join dbo.AMGR_User_Field_Defs_Tbl SCVal
     on SC.Type_Id = SCVal.Type_Id and SC.Code_Id = SCVal.Code_Id and SC.Type_Id = 119 and SCVal.Table_Id = 2

     Left Outer Join dbo.AMGR_User_Fields_Tbl SR
     on CS.Case_Id = SR.Client_Id and SR.Type_Id = 120
     Left Outer Join dbo.AMGR_User_Field_Defs_Tbl SRVal
     on SR.Type_Id = SRVal.Type_Id and SR.Code_Id = SRVal.Code_Id and SR.Type_Id = 120 and SRVal.Table_Id = 2

     Left Outer Join dbo.AMGR_User_Fields_Tbl APP
     on CS.Case_Id = APP.Client_Id and APP.Type_Id = 130
     Left Outer Join dbo.AMGR_User_Field_Defs_Tbl APPVal
     on APP.Type_Id = APPVal.Type_Id and APP.Code_Id = APPVal.Code_Id and APP.Type_Id = 130and APPVal.Table_Id = 2

     Left Outer Join dbo.AMGR_User_Field_Defs_Tbl Status
     on CS.Status = Status.Code_Id and Status.Type_Id = 60041 and Status.Table_Id = 2

--This last join gets the manual notes captured against the cases

     Left outer Join dbo.AMGR_Notes_Tbl Notes
     on CS.Case_Id = Notes.Client_Id and Notes.Type = 0

Where CS.Record_Type = 0
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Hi @Stix. As given, I'm not sure your "simple query" can be doing what you think it's doing. You are grouping by all three of the returned columns. As a result, the `max` won't really be doing anything. That query is equivalent to a SELECT DISTINCT which returns the three columns. It might be helpful to have some sample data from `AMGR_Notes_Tbl` and details of which rows should be shown (and why).

Comment: You probably want `CROSS APPLY` with a subquery

Comment: can i use Top 1 order by datecol and group by caseID?

Comment: @Stix, I think Charlieface is imagining you'd use a `TOP 1` in `CROSS APPLY` subquery. You should be able to connect this to your data with `CaseID` in the `WHERE` clause of that query (and other fields if necessary, I'm still unclear on whether it's one note per case, one note per date per case or something else).

Comment: @SteveLovell, it is the most recent note per case.. everything i try.. it doesnt bring most recent note, it just brings any note

Comment: SELECT T.Client_Id, T.TextCol, T.DateCol FROM 
(
    SELECT a.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A.client_id ORDER BY a.datecol DESC) AS rnk FROM AMGR_Notes_Tbl a
 inner join  AMGR_CSCases B on a.Client_Id = b.Case_Id
) T
WHERE T.rnk = 1
and t.Type = 0

The above seems to works.. i can see client_ID which is case_ID and one note each..
Only 11 rows though..

I just dont know how to put it in my existing query to see if it works?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to be sure without sample data and desired data from the notes table, but I believe this is what you need. In the code you originally supplied, please try replacing the final `LEFT OUTER JOIN` with the following code:

```
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 tbl.TextCol as Note, tbl.DateCol as MOT_Date
             FROM AMGR_Notes_Tbl as tbl
             WHERE notes.ClientId = cs.Case_Id AND tbl.Type = 0
             ORDER BY tbl.DateCol DESC) as Notes
```

Comment: Did this answer your question, @Stix? If so, please mark this as the accepted answer. That will reward me for my efforts and help other users find useful content should they have the same issue.